# How to make these dynamically typed functions type-safe?

Tags: python, language-agnostic, type-theory

Is there any programming language (or type system) in which you could express the following Python-functions in a statically typed and type-safe way (without having to use casts, runtime-checks etc)?

`#1`:

```
# My function - What would its type be? 
def Apply(x):
    return x(x)

# Example usage
print Apply(lambda _: 42)
```

`#2`:

```
white = None
black = None

def White():
    for x in xrange(1, 10):
        print ("White move #%s" % x)
        yield black

def Black():
    for x in xrange(1, 10):
        print ("Black move #%s" % x)
        yield white

white = White()
black = Black()

# What would the type of the iterator objects be?
for it in white:
    it = it.next()
```

Comment: No! Why do you think so?

Comment: These should be in two separate questions. The consequences of them being in the same question are evident, as most answers below tackle either, but not both. Therefore closing as _too broad_.

Comment: Go should be able to do it. Java8, too, iirc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1#**
This is not typeable with a finite type. This means that very few (if any) programming languages will be able to type this.

However, as you have demonstrated, there is a specific type for x that allows the function to be typed:

```
x :: t -> B
```

Where `B` is some concrete type. This results in `apply` being typed as:

```
apply :: (t -> B) -> B
```

Note that Hindley-Milner will not derive this type.

**2#**
This is easy to represent in Haskell (left as an exercise to the reader...)

Comment: To #2: Could you give a concrete example? I think one would implement this in Haskell in a quite different way (monads/continuations), but wouldn't typing the iterators be the same problem as in #1?

Answer (score 2):

I found a Haskell solution for **#1** using [Rank-N-Types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Polymorphism) (just for GHCi)

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
apply :: (forall a . a -> r) -> r
apply x = x x

apply $ const 42 -- Yields 42
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to example #1, you would have to specify the return type of Apply(), and then all functions x that you pass also must return this. Most statically typed languages would not be able to do that safely without checks, as the x function you pass in can return whatever.

In example #2 the type of the iterator objects are that they are iterators. If you mean what they return, they return iterators. I don't see why that wouldn't be possible in a static system, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Iterators are also generic since you need to know the type of the value it contains (Iterator<int>).

Comment: contains? Why? You need to know what they return, and in this case they return another iterator.

Comment: Wait, you mean that we can't be sure that the iterator the iterator returns returns an iterator, and that's true.

In short, no, in a static language, if use generic functions and pass them around, then no, you don't know what they return. In fact, this is typically something you do in a static language when you end up needing dynamic functionality. ;)