# Can I declare a function that can take pointer to itself as an argument?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

Reading a question in stackoverflow, I wondered whether it's possible to declare a function that takes a pointer to itself.  I.e. to make such declaration of `foo`, for which the following would be correct:

```
foo(foo);
```

The simpliest idea is casting to another function pointer (can't cast to `void*`, since it may be smaller), so the function declaration looks like this:

```
void foo(void (*)());
```

While that's OK in C (and will work with casting in C++), I wonder, whether it can be done without such hard "reinterpret" casting or losing type information.

In other words, I want the following declaration:

```
void foo( void (*)( void (*)( void (*) ( ... ))));
```

but, of course, unlimited declarations are impossible.  Naive `typedef`ing doesn't help either.

C++ templates are welcome, even if they make the calling code (`foo(foo)`) look a bit less succinct, but still *finite*.

C-style answers that show, how one can drop type information without casting, or other tricks of that sort are, of course, interesting, but won't be accepted.

Comment: Is there a functional language in which this is possible?

Comment: There are non-functional languages in which it is possible, e.g. C#

Comment: it is trivial to do in any dynamically-typed language, e.g. Python, Ruby, Perl, PHP, JavaScript, just to name a few...

Comment: @newacct, yes, that's why I asked about C. :)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/793449/10396

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I agree with Dario - making this on type level seems impossible.

But you can use classes ("strategy pattern"):

```
class A {
  void evil(A a) {       // a pointer to A is ok too
  }
};
```

You can even add operator():

```
  void operator()(A a) { return evil(a); }
```

Generally such things are better done in FP languages. Haskell version is simply:

```
data Evil = Evil (Evil -> Integer)
```

This uses a wrapper (`Evil`) that corresponds to using a class.

*From the questioner*: what this answer lacked was the ability to pass several different functions as an argument of one of them.  This can be solved either by making `evil()` virtual or by explicitly storing in the object a function pointer that implements it (which is basically the same).

With this clarification, the answer is good enough to be accepted.

Comment: Nice idea.  But I'd also like to pass more parameters along with function pointer.  I see a way of doing it with use of factory pattern to clone "functions" and passing the parameters as constructor arguments.  But this seems too tricky...

Comment: Where exactly are you passing those parameters? My naive understanding would be void operator()(A a, int x, int y) - you can regard A as the type of functions taking A and two ints and returning void. Haskell's version would be data Evil = Evil (Evil -> Integer -> Integer -> T) where T is the return type. Did I understand you? Factory pattern is currying in FP - it's much clearer in ML/Haskell, but I don't understand why it is needed here. If possible please extend the question with some example usage of those additional parameters (not neccesarily a real-world one).

Answer (score 5):

Apparently not - see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079120/how-to-make-these-dynamically-typed-functions-type-safe). The type required here would always be infinite.

Comment: I still don't see a relation between "infinite type" and "possible".  If I thought there is one, I wouldn't ask the question, would I?

Comment: All statically-typed languages I know require their types to be finite. If a type is infinite, the type-system isn't able to express this one. But go ahead, invent an infinite type system.

Comment: Infinite types are not possible to declare...? You said it yourself, "unlimited declarations are impossible".

Comment: @GMan: unlimited *declarations* are impossible, but does it *really* forbid unlimited *types*?  Something like `typedef foo(foo*);` is an example of (banned) finite declaration that declares unlimited type.

Comment: @Dario - "All statically-typed languages I know require their types to be finite." Ever heard of Haskell?

Comment: @Chris: Haskell doesn't allow infinite types, just infinite data! Or maybe you're referring to higher-rank polymorphism, but these types aren't infinite too.

Comment: C# is a statically typed language, and: `delegate void F(F f);` is a perfectly legal declaration.

Comment: @Pavel: Then give an example value for `F` that is not null.

Answer (score 5):

Another dirty trick.

```
void Foo( ... )
{
}

int main()
{
 Foo( Foo );
}
```

Above program will compile without any error. But it is not recursive. Following modified function is recursive version with a limiter.

```
#define RECURSIVE_DEPTH (5)

typedef void ( *FooType )( int, ... );

void Foo( int Depth, ... )
{
 void ( *This )( int, ... );

 va_list Arguments;

 va_start( Arguments, Depth );

 if( Depth )
 {
  This = va_arg( Arguments, FooType );

  This( Depth - 1, This );
 }

 va_end ( Arguments );  
}

int main()
{
 Foo( RECURSIVE_DEPTH, Foo );
}
```

Comment: The above programs invoke undefined behavior with void main().  main() should always be declared as returning an int in C and C++.

Comment: What's against receiving the function pointer using normal `va_arg` / `va_start` calls, without that cursed offset calculations? They seem to be unnecessary and make the whole code non-portable. Would have upvoted if those offset calculations weren't there :)

Comment: @litb - Thank you. Actually I don't know how to use `va_start` without `previous variable` argument. Is it possible to use UNIX version in windows?
I really respect your point of non-portability and removing my non-portable code..;)

Comment: There's no way to use `va_start` without a fixed argument, by design.

Answer (score 4):

**YES**

It's a variant of ["Can you write a function that returns a pointer to itself?"](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm), except that in your case, the function type recursively appears as an argumkent, not as the return type. Herb Sutters answer is reusable, though: wrap the pointer in a forward-declared proxy class.

Answer (score 2):

A related problem is returning a function pointer of same type. It comes up when implementing state machines, so it got its own [entry in the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/recurfuncp.html).

The same workarounds can be applied to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can have a function that can take itself as an argument in C++ without some kind of trickery, such as putting your function in a class, and having the function take that class as an argument.

Another way that will be possible once the new C++ standard hits is to use lambdas, and have the lambda capture itself. I think it would go something like this:

```
auto recursive_lambda = [&recursive_lambda] { recursive_lambda(); };
```

Be warned that such a statement is totally untested in any compiler that supports lambdas. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly valid use of `void *`.

```
typedef void T(void *);

void f(T *probably_me)
{
  (*probably_me)(f);
}
```

Comment: actually, that's not valid C99 as function pointers can't be cast to `void *`

Comment: Most implementations allow it, after all, every C compiler is backwards compatible to the days when `char *` was not only a system-wide alias, but it was the standard-blessed alias. But technically, @Christoph is right, and the conforming way to write this program is to declare a pointer to another function type and cast it. Still, my example passed gcc -Wall because it is a non-conforming but existing convention...

Answer (score 0):

If a function could take itself as an argument, then it could perform anonymous recursion by calling itself. But recursion is impossible in simply-typed lambda calculus (which is basically what you have here, with function types). You need to implement a fixed-point combinator using recursive functions or recursive types in order to perform anonymous recursion.

Comment: Can you please give me an idea where to find additional information? Roughly speaking I'm looking for information that would enable me to understand:

1) What is simply-typed lamda calculus
2) That this is isomorphic to it
3) That it excludes recursion

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for a bunch of useful keywords!  I bet, my next question will be "With what books can I study theory of FP?"

Comment: What does simply-typed lambda calculus have to do with C/C++?