# A typedef that refers to itself

Tags: c++

```
typedef bool (*Foo)(Foo a, Foo b);
```

How do you declare a function pointer that accepts itself in its parameters?

Comment: You can't because it's a never-ending recursive definition.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: your argument is invalid. `struct X { X* a; };` is conceptually the same, but it *is* allowed.

Comment: @ybungalobill: No it's not, a function type contains its parameters, a class type doesn't contain its members.

Comment: @ybungalobill If so, please provide a `typedef` that does it, I would like to know this too

Comment: @SethCarnegie: It can't be done in C++, but the *concept* is valid.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Replace `bool` with `Foo` and you've defined the [Y combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) type.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/06/23/standard-generic-delegate-types-part-two.aspx

Comment: @PeterAlexander I wasn't saying the concept is invalid, I was saying it can't be done with a `typedef`

Comment: A struct that refers to itself is different than a function that refers to itself.  A struct has to be able to refer to itself, or else things like linked lists would be harder to implement.

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm - same concept, just on return types.

Comment: @Xeo: C++ doesn't define what 'contains' mean, so you argument is just a sophism.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I didn't say it's possible. I said it could be possible. I don't know why they decided to take the Axiom of Foundation.

Comment: @ybungalobill a `struct` is not a `typedef` and this question is about `typedef`s

Comment: Ok, so how do you do continuation passing in C++?

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB: What you say is "there is a well-known use case for the later but I can't think of a use case for the former". It again doesn't make the concept fundamentally wrong.

Comment: How would you call such a function, assuming it is possible to typedef?

Comment: @Tergiver: you can use function objects for that. Basically, classes with an overloaded function call operator: `operator()`. Class member functions can easily refer to the class they're in.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: By passing it to itself.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/06/23/standard-generic-delegate-types-part-two.aspx

Comment: @Jeffamaphone: It's a function pointer definition, you call it the same as any other function pointer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I declare a function that can take pointer to itself as an argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514619/can-i-declare-a-function-that-can-take-pointer-to-itself-as-an-argument)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indirectly:

```
struct Foo{
  typedef bool (*FooPtr)(Foo a, Foo b);
  Foo(FooPtr p)
      : p(p)
  {}

  bool operator()(Foo a, Foo b) const{
    return p(a,b);
  }

  FooPtr p;
};

struct Bar{
    Bar(Foo f)
        : some_callback(f)
    {}

    Foo some_callback;
};

bool a_callback(Foo a, Foo b){
    return false;
}

int main() {
    Bar b(a_callback);
    b.some_callback(Foo(a_callback), Foo(a_callback));
}
```

Not that I could ever see any use in that, as you can see from my example.

Comment: That's not exactly what was asked, but it's probably as far as you can go.

Answer (score 3):

You can't express this in the type system. Although there's nothing fundamentally wrong in this, it simplifies things by eliminating cycles within the type system. It strongly reminds me of [Axiom of Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

What you can do is pass a void pointer and cast it to your type:

```
typedef bool (*Foo)(void* a, void* b);

bool f(void* a, void* b)
{
    return ((Foo)a)(a,b);
}
```

Comment: You can't cast `void*` pointers into function pointers like that. POSIX recommends using something like `void* ptr; FunctionPtrType fptr; *(void **)(&fptr) = ptr;`, to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You're right that it's implementation defined. But you can do it on any sane von Neumann architecture having `void*` and function pointers of the same size.

Comment: You can't portably cast between `void*` and function pointers, no matter how many extra levels of indirection you add.  Use another function pointer type instead.