# How to create a function type that takes itself as an argument with using or typedef?

Tags: c++, typedef, c++20, using, type-declaration

Let's say I have this:

```cpp
using sftype = void (*)(bool real, sftype target);
```

I understand that this leads to a recursive call, but the implementation was supposed to be like this:

```cpp
void someFunc(bool real, sftype another = nullptr) {
    return;
}
```

I wanted to be able to store this function in a variable like `sftype var = someFunc;`.

I understand that the problem can be solved in a number of ways, for example like this:

```cpp
using sftype = void (*)(bool real, void *const target);

void someFunc(bool real, void *const target = nullptr) {
    return;
}

void main() {
    sftype var = someFunc;
}
```

However, it looks like a cheat.

Yes, I know there is an *ancient* question on a similar topic: [Can I declare a function that can take pointer to itself as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514619/can-i-declare-a-function-that-can-take-pointer-to-itself-as-an-argument).
However, maybe now in new versions of C++ (C++20) there is a *beautiful solution* for this without losing performance (as, for example, working with classes).

**How to beautifully (and without loss of a perfomance) create a function type that takes itself as an argument?**

Comment: Sorry, there is no "beautiful solution", nor there will ever be one. C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level.

Comment: The beautiful solution involves using a functor class rather than a function type.

Comment: well, only after writing the answer I realized that the q&a you link already has the answer. Why do you think the answer you can find there is not ok in C++20 anymore?

Comment: btw not sure why the answer calls it "evil", a type with member function taking an object of that type isnt something uncommon

Comment: also not sure why you think using classes = loss of performance

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514619/can-i-declare-a-function-that-can-take-pointer-to-itself-as-an-argument

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do have a function take itself as the argument, especially since you mentioned performance.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you want to solve? What do you want to do with that type(def)?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, Actually, not really. I would like to create exactly a recursive type. The above answer provides a beautiful solution to the problem, but uses a structure.
Isn't it more expensive in terms of performance? I'm not sure the compiler will be able to optimize the structure as if it didn't exist.

Comment: @Pixelchemist, I use the recursive function argument for this function itself to indicate where exactly in the recursion to break. It may sound strange, but in my context, this is not a bad choice.

Comment: @einpoklum, function as argument is need for stop condition. Function is working with it data in global scope of certain shared library (DLL).
This is some implementation of *hooks*.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `struct` to wrap the function pointer, you can then use that `struct` in the `using`/`typedef`:

```
struct sftype_impl;

using sftype = void (*)(bool real, sftype_impl target);

struct sftype_impl
{
    sftype_impl(sftype ptr)
    : ptr(ptr)
    {
    }

    void operator()(bool real, sftype_impl target)
    {
        ptr(real, target);
    }

    operator bool()
    {
        return ptr;
    }

    sftype ptr;
};

void foo(bool real, sftype_impl target)
{
    if (target)
    {
        target(real, nullptr);
    }
}

void bar(bool real, sftype_impl target)
{
    if (target)
    {
        target(real, nullptr);
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo(true, bar);
}
```

The structure should be mostly or completely optimised away in most cases.

Comment: In C++20 I don't think you need that constructor anymore (`sftype(arg)` goes to `sftype{arg}` now when `sftype` is an aggregate). Also, IMO it'd make a lot more sense to name `sftype_impl` just `sftype` (because that's the type that you actually *use*) and `sftype` `sftype_impl` (because that's how you implement an `sftype`).

Comment: @HTNW removing the constructor doesn't work, it's needed for the implicit conversion from function pointers to `sftype_impl`: https://godbolt.org/z/n4bfM9v8o

Comment: `The structure should be mostly or completely optimised away in most cases`
Really? Will the compiler be able to do these not-so-obvious optimizations? It is clear that a person optimizes this easily, but I'm not sure with the compiler. Overall, I'm not very sure about "killing" classes that have member functions or operators. Are there any articles on this subject (about g ++, and msbuild)?

Comment: A structure with a single member will normally take no more memory than a variable with the same type. Short inline functions will be inlined whether they are class methods or global functions

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in C++ to declare a function which takes a function of its own type as a parameter.

You can have a functor with a member function which takes instances of the functor as parameters, e.g.:

```
struct Func {
    void operator()(Func f){ /*...etc... */ }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I know about functors. But that's why I asked the question, I don't want to use them. I don’t want to because they might be slower than *reinterpret_cast<sftype>(target)*. I would like something that won't affect performance in any way. I'm not quite sure about functors.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment by Eljay, you can use a functor. It can be a lambda. For sake of clarity here also the handwritten one:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    void operator()(foo& f){ }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    f(f);

    auto g = [](auto h, bool call) -> void {
        if (call) h(h,false);
        std::cout << "hello";
    };
    g(g,true);

}
```

Comment: Yes, I know about functors. But that's why I asked the question, I don't want to use them. I don’t want to because they might be slower than *reinterpret_cast<sftype>(target)*. I would like something that won't affect performance in any way. I'm not quite sure about functors.

Comment: @AlexA I dare to claim that this is as performant as any other solution. Now you can try to convince me of the opposite ;)

Comment: Yes, I will try.
I can't say for sure which optimizations each compiler can make, but I think it takes more time to process the class. For example, because when calling a member function, a pointer to the class address is passed to it. It is passed through the stack. Consequently, it takes time to shift the stack pointer, assign a value, read a value ... Yes, it's nanoseconds. There is probably something else, but this is what first came to mind.

Comment: @AlexA dont speculate too much. The class has no members, the member function does not need a `this` pointer, and I'd expect a compiler to notice that